# Eclipse and struts syntax errors in JSP files

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, struts

I'm using eclipse as my java IDE and the project I'm working on uses struts. Eclipse is telling me on any page that has struts tags that the tags are syntax errors.

E.g. my tag `<logic:equal` shows this error

> Syntax error on token "<", delete this token

but the page works just fine. How can I get eclipse to not show errors in these cases?

EDIT: Just noticed this is only when the tag is inside a `<script>` block. Tags in regular HTML work fine. Is this just an unresolved bug with my version of eclipse?

EDIT 2: posting a code block per the comment. Also added the CDATA to the file like the response suggests. I'm still getting the error in eclipse.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript1.2">
//<![CDATA[
window.onload = function ()
{
    <logic:equal value="false" name="BeanKey" property="value(RecordNotFound)">
        alert("Record not found");
    </logic:equal>
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Could you post some context around that token, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can try like this,

```
<logic:present name="BeanKey" property="value(RecordNotFound)">
<logic:equal value="false" name="BeanKey" property="value(RecordNotFound)">
    <script>
        window.onload = function ()
        {
           alert("Record not found");
         }
    </script>
</logic:equal>
</logic:present>
```

Comment: I could but there are 4 or 5 of them. I'll just ignore the warning for now. Thank you. I'll go ahead and accept this as the answer since it would fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your JavaScript into a `CDATA` block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        var javascript;
    ]]>
<script>
```

Comment: Did not fix the issue.