# <s:if> showing error while using JavaScript in JSP with Struts 2

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2, syntax-error

**My JSP code:**

```html
<script>
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
       if ($("input[name=radio_workitem]:checked").length > 0) {
            $("#id_div_workitem_detail").show();
        }
    </s:if>
</s:if>
```

on `s:if`, JSP shows compile time error when hovering mouse on it (like spell error red line under `s:if`), shows msg `"Syntax error on token "if", ( expected after this token"`

although this code works fine. No problem.

**My questions are:**

1. Why it shows error, although it works ?
2. Is this good coding practice to write Struts tag in JavaScript ?

I m using eclipse Luna IDE.

Comment: Why do you have two `</s:if>` closing elements? It's not *necessarily* a *bad* practice, but there might be more elegant ways to do it. Also, once your JS is in external files where it should be, you lose the JSP pre-processing step.

Comment: no it is typing error. only one </s:if> is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why it shows error, although it works ?

It has a syntax error, although it might work but eclipse cannot validate its syntax.

> is this good coding practice to write struts tag in javascript ?

javascript should be javascript, don't mess up jsp code with  javascript.

> I m using eclipse Luna Ide.

Eclipse is a best free IDE available in the world. But it might have bugs or missing some features important to you.

```html
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
    <script>
      if ($("input[name=radio_workitem]:checked").length > 0) {
    $("#id_div_workitem_detail").show();
      }
    </script>
</s:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18968019/892327), you can also enclose the struts markup in a `<![CDATA[]]>` section.